# Abelian tower for a group with a non-trivial centre

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation

I'm going through Lang, and on p.35 he's trying to prove that if $G$ is a $p$ group with a non-trivial centre, he states that

> If $G$ has centre $Z$, we have an abelian tower $G/Z$ by induction

what I am confused about is how he can be certain that $G/Z$ can be further subdivided into Abelian cosets (i.e. the criteria that $G_{i}/G_{i+1}$ has to be Abelian)?  I'm thinking potentially this is because at minimum we can always have

$$\{e\}\subset G/Z$$
which technically fulfills the criteria to be solvable, but this seems a bit too trivial to be used as a result?

Comment: Lang famously wrote lots of books; presumably you mean his "Algebra". Lang's Algebra has famously gone through not just multiple editions, but multiple *publishing houses*. It appears you are talking about Theorem 6.5 in the Springer "Revised Third Edition", or some subsequent edition.

Answer (score 1):

Your description of what Lang is trying to prove does not parse. Also, the talk about "abelian cosets" is nonsensical. Solvable doesn't mean "abelian cosets" (which does not even make sense; what is an "abelian coset" and what is a "nonabelian coset"?) And $\{e\}\subseteq G/Z$ is not quite right, since $e$ is an element of $G$, not of $G/Z$; it should be $\{eZ\}\subset G/Z$. You seem to have been complete at sea here.

"Solvable" means that is has an **abelian tower**. That is, a group $H$ is solvable if there exist subgroups $\{1\}=H_1\lt H_2\lt\cdots \lt H_n=G$ such that (i) For $i=1,\ldots,n-1$, $H_i$ is normal in $H_{i+1}$; and (ii) For each $i$, $i=2,\ldots,n$, the quotient $H_i/H_{i-1}$ is abelian.

(You can number then starting at the top, too; makes no difference except for how you word the statement).

The theorem in question is that if $G$ is a finite $p$-group, then two things happen:

1. $G$ is solvable; and
2. if $|G|\gt 1$, then $G$ has nontrivial center.

At this point, Lang is pointing out that if you can prove 2, then this will prove 1.

So assume that you have already proven that every nontrivial finite $p$-group has nontrivial center. You want to show that $G$ is solvable. You do induction on $|G|$. If $G$ is trivial, then it is solvable. Otherwise, we know that $G$ has nontrivial center, so $G/Z$ is a $p$-group of order strictly smaller than that of $G$. *By the induction hypothesis*, this means that $G/Z$ is solvable. And it has already been established that you can "lift" this tower to a tower
$$1 \lt Z=N_1 \lt N_2\lt\cdots\lt N_m=G$$ with $N_i/N_{i-1}$ abelian. Now notice that $N_1/\{1\} = Z/\{1\}\cong Z$ is abelian, so this is an abelian tower for $G$. This proves that $G$ is solvable, *assuming that you can prove that any nontrivial $p$-group has nontrivial center*.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused about how we can generalise the requirement that $N_{i+1}/N_i$ is abelian for the $|G|>1$ case?  My understanding is that since at the very minimum we have the normal tower $Z=N_1\subset N_2 = G$  Since the normal condition for the abelian tower is always true, why would $G/Z$ be abelian?

Comment: @Redcrazyguy No one is saying $G/Z$ is abelian. We are saying that $G/Z$ is a $p$-group of order strictly smaller than the order of $G$, so **by the induction hypothesis** we know that $G/Z$ has an abelian **tower**.